# Best way to add space on either side of page

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a ReactJS/MaterialUI webapp I'm building. I want to add space on the left and right side of my page (to look like any other page, including stack overflow). I don't know if the best practice is to add padding, or a margin. Then on mobile, I wouldn't want the space.

One idea I had was to add blank grid sections on the left and right side with breakpoints where they don't appear on mobile. I'm not sure what's considered the best approach here.

Comment: This question is either **too broad, opinion based** or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is there a way to do this without strict pixel limits?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `max-width: 1200px` and `margin: 0px auth;` on the element which wraps the entire page to achieve this.

The `margin: 0px auto` will add 0px margin top and bottom, and center the right and left margin.

```
<div className="page_wrpr">
    .......
</div>

.page_wrpr {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`.container{ width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; }`
The margin will give your container a top- and bottom-margin of 0. The auto-value that however much horizontal space remains after you've used up 900px, will be evenly split to add the whitespace on each side of the body.